# this custom validation is not working but I dont know whats happenning

Tags: excel, validation, ms-office

I know excel "programming" is not very popular among fellow programmers, however I've been struggling to get this right and management is on my neck..

I have the custom validation on excel :

```
=AND(LEN(AV15)=10,((VALUE(LEFT(AV15,2)))<=31),NOT(ISERROR(VALUE(LEFT(AV15,2)))),MID(AV15,3,1)="/",((VALUE(MID(AV15,4,2)))<=12),NOT(ISERROR(VALUE(MID(AV15,4,2)))),MID(AV15,6,1)="/",((VALUE(RIGHT(AV15,4)))<=2100),NOT(ISERROR(VALUE(RIGHT(AV15,4)))))
```

The validation above is supposed to accept any valid date in the format:

```
dd/mm/yyyy
```

It seems to be working partially, but somehow it wont accept a day lower than "12", example:

```
 14/12/2010 -->accepted
 13/10/2010 -->accepted
 25/10/2010 -->accepted
 12/10/2010 -->gives error
```

At first glance one would thing that the `((VALUE(MID(AV15,4,2)))<=12)` is causing this behavior, but I changed it to 31 and I still get the error, I need the validation to admit inputs  in :

```
 nn/nn/nnnn
```

where "n" is a number, i don't care if they input 99/99/9999 I can check that later on vba code, but the input has to specifically have the 10 characters.

any help would be  highly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put your formula in and when you put a `'` before the date it works just fine. What is going on is that when you put any value below `13` as the day it evaluates the date like a `date`, which is stored as a `number` in Excel. When you have above `13` it evaluates as a `string`. So what you need to do is format the cell to `Text` format. Then it should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

To see if the following works, put the date value in A1

A1 -> '14/12/2010

Put the following formulas as mentioned below

B1 -> `=MID(A1,3,1) = "/"`
C1 -> `=MID(A1,6,1) = "/"`
D1 -> `=IFERROR(AND(VALUE(MID(A1,4,2)) >= 1, VALUE(MID(A1,4,2)) <= 12), FALSE)`
E1 -> `=AND(VALUE(RIGHT(A1,4))>=2000,AND(VALUE(RIGHT(A1,4))<=2100))`
F1 -> `=AND(B1,C1,D1, E1)`

The formulas above are splitted and you will have to combine them (as it is done in cell F1).
Hope that helps.

**EDIT**: The combined formula for validation will be (**note** that I have used A1 as the cell)

```
=AND(MID(A1,3,1) = "/", MID(A1,6,1) = "/", IFERROR(AND(VALUE(MID(A1,4,2)) >= 1, VALUE(MID(A1,4,2)) <= 12), FALSE), AND(VALUE(RIGHT(A1,4))>=2000,AND(VALUE(RIGHT(A1,4))<=2100)))
```

Comment: i've done that too, all the evaluations give TRUE,  even if I put the formula on a cell it gives true, only when i add it on the Data> Validation  i get the error, I'm using excel 2003 btw.

Comment: @Rafael.IT: Looking at Jon49's answer, I should have added to put apostrophe before date input as mentioned in my answer :)

Comment: hey I did while I was testing it  but I couldn't tell the end user to add it I  had to fix it so they don't have to do anything else, but anyway you are right your answer is useful too so +1.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not simply choose the correct format in the cell?

1. Right click in the cell and select 'Format Cell'
2. Select 'Custom' from the left side navigation
3. In the 'Type:' box enter this: dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: I need it to be stored as a string, i tried your suggestion before posting, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Excel appears to be recognising values such as `10/12/2010` as dates and storing them internally in a different format, such as the number of days since Jan 1 1900 or suchlike.  It happens that when you use `LEFT`, `MID` and `RIGHT` on these date values, Excel doesn't do the conversion back from its internal format.  In particular, I put `10/12/2010` in cell A1 and `=LEFT(A1,10)` in cell B1. Cell B1 then showed me the value `40522`. (I'm in the UK and using Excel 2010 Starter.  You may get different values in other locales or with other versions of Excel.)

Try replacing all occurrences of `AV15` in your formula with `TEXT(AV15, "DD/MM/YYYY")`.  Alternatively, put `=TEXT(AV15, "DD/MM/YYYY")` in another cell and use this other cell in your formula in place of `AV15`.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't wary of VBA, then what about a simple UDF?

```
Public Function DateFormat(rng As Range)
  Dim regEx As Object

  Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

  regEx.Pattern = "\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d"
  test = regEx.Execute(rng.Value).Count > 0
End Function
```

This should return true if the value of a cell matches nn/nn/nnnn where n is any number.
Then you could simply say `=DateFormat(AV15)`