# Save a csv with data in columns using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I made a Macro in Excel-VBA that :

- Creates a new worksheet
- Writes data into 5 columns
- Saves the file as a CSV
- Closes the file

The problem is, once the file is closed, the data is no longer separated in columns. But it's comma separated and concatenated into one single column.

**Oddly enough, closing the recently created csv file manually (and not closing it in VBA) solves this issue, as the data will still be in columns when opening it again.**.

***What I'm trying to do here, is to save/close the file in VBA, and keep the data in columns.***

Here's an exemple :

```
Sub test()
    Workbooks.Add
    Cells(1, 1) = "a"
    Cells(1, 2) = "a"
    Cells(1, 3) = "a"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:= "C:\Users\user\Desktop\File.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
End Sub
```

Then closing "File.csv" manually and opening it again :

[image]

Second exemple :

```
Sub test()
    Workbooks.Add
    Cells(1, 1) = "a"
    Cells(1, 2) = "a"
    Cells(1, 3) = "a"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:= "C:\Users\user\Desktop\File.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

The file is closed automatically here. Here is the result when it is opened manually :

[image]

Comment: Add this `ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True` before `End Sub` in the second example. I tested that and it worked fine.

Comment: out of my head, I think you can set the separation character. In stead of using the comma, use TAB. check: http://superuser.com/questions/476327/how-do-i-save-an-excel-spreadsheet-as-a-semi-colon-separated-values-file

Comment: @Santosh Didn't help, the output is the same as exemple 2.

Comment: @Eric My computer's separator is set to ";" not "," and I still get a comma.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18492514/2224701

Comment: @Vojtěch Dohnal It worked, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Sub test()

    Workbooks.Add
    Cells(1, 1) = "a"
    Cells(1, 2) = "a"
    Cells(1, 3) = "a"

    With ActiveWorkbook
        .SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\user\Desktop\File.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, Local:=True
        .Close False
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, this will work. Explanation: Since VBA does everything in EN_US locale per default, it uses a comma as CSV delimiter per default. There is a parameter `Local` in `SaveAs` to avoid this and use the delimiter set in locale settings. But then you must close the workbook **without** saving after the `SaveAs`. If not, the `.Close SaveChanges:=True` will use the comma again.